Join/Mix dynamic and static values on Array = alternative to HSTACK that works in older MS Excel version (No VBA, please)
I need to join some value(s) from some cell(s) with a "static" bunch of other values into an Excel array... BUT I'd like to avoid using VBA for it and I need something that works also with older Excel version: at least MSO Excel 2010.
I know I could get what I need very easily in MSO Excel 365, without VBA, by simply using HSTAK function, for example this way: =SUMPRODUCT(CONCATENATE(HSTACK($A$1,"Const1","Const2","Const3"),"/",K$2)*1)
(Don't mind the result: that is a very simplified representative version of my real formula, anyway it suffice to focus on the matter here.)
HSTACK would let me obtain the "mixed dynamic/static array" I need, and it works ...BUT only on MS Excel 365, unfortunately.
As I said, I need a way to make things work also on older Excel version (at least Excel 2010), so...
Ultimately: looking for an alternative I can't figure out myself... can you help me please?
P.S.
I tried to do without HSTACK this way: =SUMPRODUCT(CONCATENATE({$A$1,"Const1","Const2","Const3"},"/",K$2)*1)
but it gives error! (Of course, dynamic and static values can't be joined together into an Excel array that way...)
EDIT:
I'll accept Mayukh Bhattacharya answer: his approach do the job for me and works in Excel 2010. The only downside is, unfortunately, the formulas are going to get very long when you have a lot of dynamic+static values to join together (I put only 4 in my example here but... Imagine what will happen when you have hundreds of them...!) In the long run, there's the risk you may face having to deal with Excel limits for formula length. So... I still hope someone could improve it suggesting a more concise formula/approach for this in the future.
P.S.
I tried something myself (with no luck, unfortunately): since the initial problem was due to mixing one or more dynamic values and static values in an Excel array, I thought I could modify Mayukh Bhattacharya putting at least all static values in a separated Excel array, I expected this way to have the possibility to reduce the formula length and have half of the "formula-length-problem" solved with something like =SUMPRODUCT(CONCATENATE(CHOOSE({1,2},$A$1,{"Const1","Const2","Const3"}),"/",K$2)*1) ...but it doesn't work (I get an #N/D error)
So, again, if someone could improve or suggest a way to shorten down the formula for this, please let me know... Thanks!

Look into CHOOSE() function. But I am doubtful whether it is available or not, as MSFT documentation shows it is not available while in another website it says it is applicable from Excel 2007. Here

Show sample data and expected result in a spreadsheet, because at the moment it's a mixture of texts, operators, and cell references and I don't really know what's going on here.

@MGonet "Const1" or "Const2" or Const3 are all numbers within speechmarks with constant or static op meant to say that, and those can't be a text its an example as far i can see. And Yes I have found CHOOSE() does works in Excel 2010 but dont know why MS365 doesnt show the year 2010 and only shows 2013 for the said function.

CHOOSE is definitely available in Excel 2007 because I also have that version.

But if you see the MSFT documentations it does not shows up, as far i know it was showing earlier.

Let "Const1" denote the number 12, let K$2 contain 5, then "12/5"*1 represents the date. That's it? Is the whole formula representing the sum of dates?

@MGonet no no not really, dont think so

@MGonet : please, don't mind concentrating on the formula result here, it's just an example, that's not the "real" point, trust me. What I'm asking and need so far is just a way to obtain an array in Excel formula mixing/joining dynamic and static values/parts and that works also for older Excel versions.

@MayukhBhattacharya : I confirm you: CHOOSE() function works with Excel 2010 and, indeed, it could be a possible solution here (see my comment to your answer for more on it, thank you)

In Excel 2010 the following should work:
=SUMPRODUCT(CONCATENATE(CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},$A$1,"Const1","Const2","Const3"),"/",K$2)*1)


NOTES: One may need to hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER while exiting the edit mode. 


Thanks! Indeed, your CHOOSE example works as a solution for me using Excel 2010. The only downside using this approach is, unfortunately, the formulas are going to get very long when you have a lot of dynamic+static values to join together (I put only 4 in the example above but mind that isn't the real formula I'm using that is w-a-a-a-y more complex than that) and, in the long run, there's the risk you may face having to deal with Excel limits for formula length...

Anyway, I upvoted your answer already, just waiting some more days to see if someone can suggest a more convenient way (one that produces a more concise formula for the purpose) before accepting answer... If no one will come with an idea along these lines I'll accept your answer. Thanks again
